# package explorer is broken

Tags: eclipse

this is what I`ve done

I clicked on a project with right button and I`ve selected open in new window. I had 2 windows. First  I've closed the primary one, then the new one. After that every time when I run eclipse the project that I've selected to open in new window was the default one. My package explorer every time was in it and I had to click back. I just deleted this project and now I can't navigate in package explorer. It is still set to this project but I can't go back. What can I do ? How can I select the basic package explorer view ?

Comment: Isn't the title a bit extreme   ... and non-specific?

Comment: The title isn't extreme. I've experienced this before and it was quite frustrating. I have an answer for it below.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an *Up one level* or a *Back* button enabled on the Package explorer view toolbar - I am not talking about the main toolbars similar buttons but one just under the view header. These buttons shall allow you to return to the original level with multiple projects visible.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Up One Level button that Zoltan is referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Symptom:***

The package explorer dialog looks as if you have drilled down into an end node but the dialog is blank and there is no "Up One Level"/"Back Button" to click.

***Solution:***

1. Ensure eclipse is not running
2. Delete the following file:

   **workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml**
3. Start Eclipse

The workbench.xml file contains settings for the state of the package explorer among other things. I suspect that the package explorer settings get corrupted somehow.

Comment: Works Great :) for future people having this problem this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Top right there is ViewMenu option menu (triangle downside oriented) - try some options there, or click project explorer tab(top left) and try refresh etc. It is hard to see what exactly happened to you.

Answer (score 0):

In `Eclipse`, <kbd>Window</kbd> → <kbd>Reset Perspective</kbd>...